# How can i fix or freeze the subset of convolution filter in Pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

```
for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(testloader):
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    inputs = inputs.float().cuda()
    inputs, targets = inputs.to(device), targets.to(device)


    outputs = im_net(inputs)


    ce_loss = criterion(outputs, targets)

    loss = criterion(outputs, targets)


    loss.backward()
    im_net.features[25].weight.grad[temp_5.values] = 0

    print(im_net.features[25].weight.grad[temp_5.values])


    optimizer.step()
```

Above is my code for trying to fix the subset (`temp_5.values`) of 25th convolution layer's filter. I try to set the subset filter's gradient as 0 so not to update.
When I try to print the gradient, they are all zero, but the weight has been changed.

So two questions:

1. I wonder why the zero gradient makes the weight change;
2. Is there other solution to fix the subset convolution filter?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that in pytorch is by setting requires_grad to False.

This line should do the trick:

```
im_net.features[25].weight.requires_grad = False
```

Comment: Sorry it doesnt work. All the weight can be set requires_grad = False. But I need to freeze the specific weight not all weight. But thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting `requires_grad` to `False` before calling `loss.backward`?